# Editing <html>, <head>, <body> etc. in WYSIWYG editor

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe, wysihtml5

I'm using the WYSIHTML5 editor: http://xing.github.io/wysihtml5/

This editor adds an iFrame to the page and updates a textarea whenever you make a change to the iFrame's `contenteditable` body. It's similar to many other WYSIWYG editors, so my issue should apply to other editors.

My issue is I want to be able to edit `<html>`, `<head>`, `<body>` and other important base tags through this editor. You obviously can't edit them in WYSIWYG mode, so raw code mode would be fine.

When I enable these tags, they are stripped out by the browser itself because those tags have already been opened by the page in the iFrame itself. So when I switch between raw code and WYSIWYG modes, they are lost.

I use the default "advanced" parser rules and merge them with these: http://pastebin.com/6QvYkqm4 with jQuery's recursive `$.merge()`.

**How can I get around this but still use this plugin? Have I misconfigured the plugin?** I'm sure I've enabled the tags in the parser rules.

Comment: split on (/<body/i)[1] and (/\/body>/i)[0] to populate the editor, then sandwich back to save. you can edit the head in a textarea or escape the xml entities and edit in a contenEditable div. i recommend a textarea for simplicity. an overall "edit as html" toggle for your wysiwyg editor is handy for dev work.

Answer (score 1):

I highly recommend you use as [JQuert TE](http://jqueryte.com/) WYSIHTML textarea editor though even it it is buggy, but compared to many others its alot better.

The JavaScript libraries with which WYSIHTML editors are built with search for those tags and deletes them because it's a security flaw not to, and it will probably warp a site layout if its left in.  Imagine if a user changes the page's headers. If you really want to implement those feature I would suggest you find the code that deletes those tags in WYSIHTML5's library and alter it to not recognize the those specific tags. Good luck.

Edit:

Example:
In the folder parser_rules of WYSIHTML5 select advanced.js or basic.js (depends what you are using) find:

```
"head": {
        "remove": 1
},
```

replace with:

```
"head": {
        "rename_tag": "head"
    },
```

Repeat this process with different rules that until you have a desired rule set. WYSIWYG textarea editors all have different JavaScript librarys but the one your using is simple enough to edit.

Comment: it's not the js wysiwiwyg libs that remove head and body, it's the html parser of the browser...

Answer (score 0):

A WYSIWYG editor is not the solution you're looking for since you can't "see" (format with styles) the `head` or markup of a page. You should take a look at http://codemirror.net/

[HTML example page](http://codemirror.net/mode/htmlmixed/index.html)